# Is it ok to use drop-down menus in Mobile Website?

Tags: usability, mobile, menu, mobile-web, dropdown

Is it ok to use drop-down menus in a Mobile Website which opens on clicking? Like http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: That really depends on the screen resolution.

Comment: What's it for? A navbar menu? A dropdown for a web form?

Comment: You mean the arrow in the top right corner of the mobile version of the site? Why wouldn't it be okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple answer here.  Some of the pro's and con's that you need to think through to decide on the subjective issue of what is best for your application are:

**Pros**

- Easily extendible
- Familiar to most users (this is arguably more for desktop apps)

**Cons**

- They encourage lazy UX design
- They don't lend themselves to scanning well (little shape or position information for people to go for)
- Low discoverability.  You have to click on it to know what is there.

That said there are many applications where it *does* make sense to use them, the most common probably being the Safari browser taskbar.

[image]

As a general rule though I would avoid using them unless absolutely necessary.  Too often they are taken as an easy way out of a UX problem when there are better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use one. I think the best way to use a drop down menu on mobile is to expand it to fully cover or push the content down. That way you avoid clutter. Like always on mobile keeping the menu items to a bare minimum is essential for a delighful experience.